# while embed tag not loaded data i want to show my custom loader but not working

Tags: javascript, html

**Onload and other events of embed tag is not working**

```js
 function get_loader() {
        console.log('loader comes..');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<embed src="http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="750px" onload="get_loader()">
```

Comment: Note that the function is called *after* the embed is loaded. I believe another function is needed that would be called on page load, before the embed.

Comment: but i want to fire event on embed only load see argument i passed onload but its not working

Comment: You are trying to load `.pdf`. but some browsers not support pdf format. Some browsers can't view pdf directly then they try to download. Your plugin is not supported. Try with different file.

Comment: no its working fine for chrome and firefox both but the problem is while its loading i want to show my custom loader thats why i am doing this and the embed tag is in modal